# Not sure I understand this nested ternary operation

Tags: conditional-operator

Could use some help understanding (or help with corrections), and either an explanation or link as to how you know so I can figure these out when I run into them again. None of the tutorials I found were terribly helpful. Here's the operation. The bracket denotes a time series (array):

```
a = b==1 ? c ? d : e > a[1] ? e : a[1] : c ? d : a[1]
```

Translated, would be:

```
a = if b==1 and c then d 
    else if e > a[1] then e 
    else a[1] 
    else if c then d
    else a[1]
```

...right? If correct, I don't understand how an else can come between two else-ifs. Doesn't the chain stop evaluating after the first else? I thought else essentially means "otherwise."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the execution would be equivalent to this instead of `b == 1 and c`:

```
function test() {
    if (b==1) {
        if (c) {
            return d;
        } else {
            if (e > a[1]) {
                return e;
            } else {
                return a[1];
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (c) {
            return d;
        } else {
            return a[1];
        }
    }
}

a = test();
```

Comment: Thanks. Any tutorials you know of that could help in the future?

Comment: @sgjohnson1981 Here is a website that can convert ternary expressions to if-else: http://converter.website-dev.eu/